# "the only left independent bookstore"

Tags: grammaticality

Is:

> I will go to the only left independent bookstore in my city

a correct expression?

It doesn't sound exceptionally good to me... could you advise on how to express the same meaning in a better way?

Comment: ... the only independent bookstore left in my city ...

Comment: (Posting as a comment because I can't explain *why* any of this is true) If you want to use "left", it has to come after "bookstore": *...to the only independent bookstore left in...*. If you use "remaining" instead of "left", it can go in both places: *...to the only remaining independent bookstore...* or *...to the only independent bookstore remaining...*

Comment: It's correct if it's the only "liberal" bookstore in your city, or, perhaps, the only one on the left bank of the river.  Otherwise as @bib said.

Comment: Hearing this, I would wonder if the store in question carried Socialist manifestos and copies of Mao's Little Red Book.

Comment: Was not the answer provided 6 hours ago by @Bib.

Comment: I would typically say "The last independent bookstore remaining in my city."  To me, saying "last" instead of "only" is a bit more clear.  I can't prove why it's a good construction, but I thought I'd post as a comment.

Comment: @weakphoneme But oerkelens *explained* it.

Answer (score 13):

There are *some* adjectives that do not *precede* the noun they modify, but the *follow* it.

*Left*, in the sense of *remaining* (and coming from the verb *leave*) is one of those.

Note that strictly speaking *left* as opposing *right* is an adjective, but *left* meaning "remaining" is a participle that can be used attributively. It is used in some ways *like* an adjective, but it's not exactly the same thing.

We *can* use *left* preceding a noun, but then it is the opposite of *right*:

> Will you take the left door or the right door?

If I remove one of the two doors:

> There is only one door left.

So the correct phrasing of your sentence would be

> I will go to the only independent book store left in my city.

Unless you *do* mean a book store that sells books expressing specific political views...

Comment: Thanks, just a a little side question: if I had to use `I will be going` instead of `I will go` , can I still use `to` after that, or does it become `at` ?

Comment: +1 But interestingly, you could say *I will go to the only remaining bookstore ...*

Comment: @jj_the preposition doesn't change just because of the verb tense, so it stays _to_. You can "go _at_ the bookstore", but that would give the impression you would relieve yourself there...

Comment: @bib true, _remaining_ is an interesting adjective, it can go after _and_ before the noun.

Comment: I don't believe that "left", in that context, is an adjective.  Seems pretty verbish to me.

Comment: @HotLicks: strictly speaking, following Pullum, it's not an adjective, but an attributively used participle. I'm not sure that distinction is 100% relevant here, but I will add a note :)

Comment: @oerkelens well libraries sometime have reading rooms, and reading could be relieving so.. :)

Answer (score 4):

In idiomatic American English, we would tend to say, "I am going to the only independent bookstore left in my city".

A "left independent bookstore" implies they are politically-leaning to the Liberal end of the spectrum. And that *might* be what is meant - but it's most likely not.

Comment: Note that there are countries where *liberal* (and/or *neo-liberal*) are terms associated with the political right. A *left bookstore* might cater to Trotskyists, or anarchists, or other rather illiberal types.

Comment: @choster - but not in the US, which is where I specified the usage to be =D

Comment: Why did you call this idiomatic?

Comment: @twip - because *technically* there wasn't anything "wrong" with the OP's sentence (other than spelling on "independent"); it just doesn't sound like a native speaker

Comment: What I meant was: how is the following sentence idiomatic? "I am going to the only independent bookstore left in my city."

Comment: @twip - it's idiomatic because we wouldn't say "only left independent bookstore" in American English. It 'sounds wrong' to the US ear.

Comment: I understand that what was asked in the question was nonstandard, but not ungrammatical. What I am asking is why *you* would call your example sentence idiomatic: just trying to zero in here. We aren't calling this idiomatic in terms of meaning, but in terms of form? 

"The syntactical, grammatical, or *structural* form peculiar to a language." (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiom )

Comment: @twip - yes, the *form* :)

Answer (score 3):

"I will go to the only indepen**dent** bookstore left in my city" or, preferably, "I will go to the only remaining independent bookstore in my city"

Comment: you still say "independent bookstore remaining" .. putting the "remaining" before "independent bookstore" makes it sound non-native (as an American, that is)

Comment: As Al Stewart sings: "There is an independent bookstore, the last one that remains, all the others you might look for have been eaten by the chain ..."

Comment: @warren I'm American and "only remaining independent bookstore" sounds more natural than putting "remaining" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The normal construction would be 'the only independent bookstore left in my city', with the presumption that all the other bookstores in town were chain stores.

In some cities where political specialty bookstores can thrive (San Francisco or London, e.g.), then it is possible the speaker could mean the only *left-wing* or *leftist* bookstore,  but then "independent" would probably be redundant.